# Android facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, api, request

i'm just trying to use the facebook api in my android application, my code is :

```
public class FacebookActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }



        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
```

I think this is the base but i don't know how to do it properly.
I have a button to connect to my facebook accompte, but in my method onSucces, i don't know what i have to put in.
My second question is about request. I want to integrate a friend request in this same app but i don't found any informations if someone can help me.
Thanks you

Comment: Unclear what is being asked. To help us help you, edit your question. Seriously: show it to a friend, and see if he/she understands.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        facebook:com_facebook_confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:com_facebook_tooltip_mode="never_display"/>
```

Used this in your xml file